# fadeOut DIV element if var TRUE

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a div named #slider that is 400% wide, with the overflow-x set to hidden. #slider DIV  is filled with 4 divs at 25% (so that each div stretches 100% of the DOM). Once the page loads, I immediately move the div -100% left, so that the div can move left and right from the page load.

I am animating the #slider DIV, moving it left and right to move each child DIV into view in DOM, using a simple:

```
$(".goright").click(function(){
$("#slider").animate({left:'-=100%'}, 400);
});
```

and

```
 $(".goleft").click(function(){
 $("#slider").animate({left:'+=100%'}, 400);
 });
```

respectively.

Which works brilliantly.

However, I am attempting to fadeOut the buttons that make the slider move, once the position of #slider reaches <= -300% or >= 0%. Fading the other back in if it is hidden.

The following code appears to work once the page has initially loaded:

```
// Make the right slide work
$(".goright").click(function(){
    if ($('.goleft').is (':hidden')) {
        $('.goleft').fadeIn();
    };
    $("#slider").animate({left:'-=100%'}, 400, function() {
         var leftPos = $('#slider').css('left');
         if (leftPos >= '-300%') {
              $('.goright').fadeOut(200);}
        });

    });

// Make the left slide work
$(".goleft").click(function(){
    if ($('.goright').is (':hidden')) {
        $('.goright').fadeIn();
    };
    $("#slider").animate({left:'+=100%'}, 400, function() {
         var leftPos = $('#slider').css('left');

         if (leftPos >= '0%') {
              $('.goleft').fadeOut(200);}
        });

    });
```

But it seems that if the page is resized after it has been rendered, the right control button fails to fade out at the correct left value, fading out too early.

Any ideas what is going wrong? Any help appreciated!

You can see the website here: http://www.newactorscompany.com/new/indexx.html

Comment: In fact, the button fade out late when I checked. I mean if I continuously click the right/left control button , I am reaching a blank page and the buttons doesn't work after that.

Answer (score 0):

i would go by different way to show/hide arrows based on frames. if you show first frame, then hide left arrow. if you show last frame then hide right arrow. by simple frame counter. not by position, because it looks that position changes as you resize window, even using percents.